# UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter ---- swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

"cmd + N"  I build a UICollectionViewController 
[image]

[image]

Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post text as actual text. Do not post pictures of text.

Comment: And please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UICollectionView+must+be+initialized+with+a+non-nil+layout+parameter+%5Bswift%5D) before posting.